Why lemmatizer is not working while stemming works
Hi I was working on a dataset where i performed stopwords removal on an string array and removed stopwords later i performed stemming on the data after removal of stopwords,
While trying to perform lemmatizer The output is not as expected,
lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer() After_lemmatization =[' '. join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in word_tokenize(text)]) for text in without_stopwords] print(len(without_stopwords[1])) print(len(After_lemmatization[1])) print(After_lemmatization[1])
This is the code I tried for lemmatizer, I havent faced any error while executing but i feel like the lemmatization is not working at all as i can see that there is no difference in the length of even after performing the issue for kind information i had imported required package for WordNetLemmatizer
Please help me as early as possible
